# Issues connecting ibm mq client to a lower version

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I am using 7x (7.5 mq client amqmdnet.dll) via .net and using `MQPutMessageOptions` and `MQGetMessageOptions`, this code works fine with mq 7.5 ibm client, however

[IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21312967)

says 7x mq client will be backward compatible with 6x, when i try to connect, i get this error (am in a windows 7 64-bit OS).

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.CommonServices' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnabled()
   at IBM.WMQ.MQBase..ctor()
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..cctor()
```

The line that throws the above error is :

```
MQQueueManager  mqQMgr = new MQQueueManager("My queue manager" , "my channel name" ,"my connection name");
```

PS: the above line with the same params work fine in 7.5 mq client , but fails when a 6x (for ex: 6.0.2.5 mq client is installed, i have done 'typical' installation (full installation of 6x mq client).

Any idea how to make it work with 6.0.2.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that link is correct. What the link is saying if you have MQ v7.5 client installed, you will be able to work with MQ v6.0 queue manager running on a remote machine. But what you are trying appears to be different. You appear to have compiled the application with MQ v7.5 client but trying to run it on MQ v6.0.x client. This will not work.